# How do turn my mac touchpad into a midi controller?

Tags: macos, midi, vst, trackpad

I want to write a custom script/program that would allow me to send the signal from my mac trackpad to midi. I dont even know where to start though, im a c# programmer so not to easy for me :-(

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Pete

Comment: I would recommend checking out the [OSX driver documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_HardwareDrivers/_index.html) I *really* don't think that C# will be useful. *Maybe* obj-c?

Comment: You need to write an iOS application that sends MIDI over network, and then write an application for the PC that can receive this MIDI data.  Why not just use one of the many applications that already does this?